# Typescript: How to use a generic parameter as object key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to write an interface that accepts a string constant as one of its parameters, and uses that as the key of an object?

For instance, assuming I make two different GraphQL requests, both of which return a `User`, but under different key names:

```js
const userByIdResult = {
  data: {
    userById: {
       id: 123,
       username: 'joseph'
    }
  }
}

const userByUsernameResult = {
  data: {
    userByUsername: {
       id: 123,
       username: 'joseph'
    }
  }
}
```

I would imagine writing a generic interface would go something like this:

```
interface GraphQLResponse<QueryKey, ResponseType> {
  data: {
    [QueryKey]: ResponseType
  }
}

interface User {
    username: string
    id: string
}

type UserByIdResponse = GraphQLResponse<'userById', User>
type UserByUsernameResponse = GraphQLResponse<'userByUsername', User>
```

But, [this doesn't work](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJTgBwBYEUAyAShAM6YD2IJEAPLgK7QCeA0hEwDTLFmXUAqTTBAB8yAN4AoZMgAmcMHABcE6TOQBtBszZMAuip4UqEQcLUBfSVcmhIsRCgCq1KKvXJ6rkHAC2EFRIwKFAAczUZYFlA4LDrSUkwIWdXACEmAElZIz4UAF40DBwCHJMaAHIvaHSs8q4XaBFE5OQGqHS2n39S6mQC9Cw8IlJjagqq9qZOvwg61tcmySA).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're close. This falls under the [category of Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). You need to make two changes:

1. `QueryKey extends string`
2. `key in QueryKey`

```
interface GraphQLResponse<QueryKey extends string, ResponseType> {
    data: {
        [key in QueryKey]: ResponseType;
    }
}

interface User {
    username: string;
    id: number;
}

type UserByIdResponse = GraphQLResponse<'userById', User>;
type UserByUsernameResponse = GraphQLResponse<'userByUsername', User>;
```

[Example Usage](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJTgBwBYEUAyAShAM6YD2IJEAPLgK7QCeA0hE8hAB6QgAmJZCTBRQAcwA0yYmUrUAKk0wQAfMgDeAKGQ7kfOGDgAuDdt3mA2gGt2yUMgbM2TALomZFKhEXKA3GZ0AX01gzVBIWEQUAFVqKFNzejiQOABbCBNhURAxf3NgPhMQelSAI2h-ULAlGLiAISYAST4PORQAXjQMHAJWrxoAciToBuaBqVjoFX9q5WRJqAaFlPS+6mRO9Cw8IlJPakHhxaZltIhx+bjpzU0EOTBkI9GW0noAGzATBee1joTdfSGExacyJepNQr-UGggomACMACYAMwSALQ3RHFYZZADABW5GoOAGaPMwVJIX8t3uj3Bp1Wrw+X1pyTOvw2UL0BmMHLBIxOLPSwJJ6NhyERKOF0MxZxMeIJECJkuQZN0wUClLuVAeTyaMneYDq5HIqSZfOabM6IIBXKF6JpfLp2Ktdp0ovFqJdGIF2LlhOwxLtKqCISAA)

```
const userByIdResult: UserByIdResponse = {
    data: {
        userById: {
            id: 123,
            username: 'joseph'
        }
    }
}

const userByUsernameResult: UserByUsernameResponse = {
    data: {
        userByUsername: {
            id: 123,
            username: 'joseph'
        }
    }
}

const userByIdResultBoom: UserByIdResponse = {
    data: {
        userByUsername: {
            id: 123,
            username: 'joseph'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation! I was completely baffled by this because `[key in x]` makes it sound like you are looping through an array so I was a little thrown.