# Should we use "any" when transforming a generic json response

Tags: typescript, apollo

I am not sure whether it is good to create a function with any type in input/ output for the function in a typescript project, and how to strike a balance between "strict type checking" and "flexibility".

Now I am trying to create a helper function to remove the edges and node in graphQL response for easier handle in view components, take an example:

```
// Input A
{
    "students": {
        "edges": [
            {
                "node": {
                    "name": "Peter",
                    "age": 12
                }
            },
            {
                "node": {
                    "name": "Mike",
                    "age": 12
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

// Input B
{
    "teachers": {
        "edges": [
            {
                "node": {
                    "name": "Mary",
                    "age": 40
                }
            },
            {
                "node": {
                    "name": "John",
                    "age": 35
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My proposed helper function:

```
const simpleConnectionsHandler = (obj: any): any => {
// Some logic to remove edges and nodes
...
}
```

Expect what I can get from the function (output):

```
// Output A
{
    "students": [
        { "name": "Peter", "age": 12 },
        { "name": "Mike", "age": 12 }
    ]
}

// Output B
{
    "teachers": [
        { "name": "Mary", "age": 40 },
        { "name": "John", "age": 35 }
    ]
}
```

In my view components I am going to take the simplified version of response like this:

```
const studentList: studentsSimplified = simpleConnectionsHandler(inputA); 
const teacherList: teachersSimplified = simpleConnectionsHandler(inputB);
```

The reason I do that is, I would like to prevent declare two versions of type for the response json, one is the response with edges and node, and one is the response without edges and node.

I would like to know whether it is good to accept input as "any" and return "any" for the output, and I convert back to the simplified version of response when I get back the result in the caller side.

Comment: Sounds like a design decision. To me, "simpleConnectionsHandler" seems to communicate that it's making a request. However, the actual functionality seems to be unwrapping objects from a graph structure.
The first thing to do is understand what responsibility you are separating and encapsulating.

If it is a conceptually consistent operation that happens to have multiple return types, then you can use a generic https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Thanks @farlee2121, in the example it assumed the input/ output of the function belongs to the same type. In my case, where input and output should be two different types, how can I resolve it without using `any` here

Comment: this is more like a `typescript` question than `reactjs`. If you tag correctly, it will be more likely to be answered by typescript people

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem to be a job for generics because all of your types are well-defined.

I would suggest defining the node type itself, and then just describe the graph format as below:

```
type MyNode = { name: string, age: number };
type graph = {
    [x: string]: {
        edges: Array<{
            node: MyNode
        }>
    }
};

function name(params: graph): { [x: string]: MyNode[] } {
    return {...}
}
```

Replace the generic `[x: string]` with any known keys you have.

As you see in this code fragment, i have described the whole input with all the expected fields, so not just any js objects can come in.

I have defined the one type MyNode and this can be used to compose the rest of the graph, as well as composing the return type.

If you even want to limit what `[x: string]` can become, you can see here:
[Typescript: How to use a generic parameter as object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419558/typescript-how-to-use-a-generic-parameter-as-object-key)

and actually write a generic function that guarantees the outcome to have the same key.

eg:

```
type knownKeys = 'teacher' | 'student';
type MyNode = { name: string, age: number };
type graph<T extends knownKeys> = {
    [x in T]: {
        edges: Array<{
            node: MyNode
        }>
    }
};

function myFunction<T extends knownKeys>(params: graph<T>): { [x in T]: MyNode[] } {
    return {}
}

// use
const a = myFunction<'teacher'>({
    teacher: {
        edges: [
            { node: { name: 'hi', age: 42, } },
        ],
    }
});
```

Comment: What if `MyNode` (i.e. the attributes in json) is even dynamic? @vickson There are different kinds of json I can pass in, without a standard type/ structure. This helper function (simpleConnectionsHandler) is serving a transformation purpose for any graphQL response

Comment: depends on how well you can predict that MyNode is going to be, you can always describe its structure to your best. If you have no clue what it is going to be, explicitly stating `any` is the solution, coz you are explicitly stating that "not even i know what is going to be thrown to me".

Comment: On the other hand, you can always use union type to list out all the possible formats you are going to receive. see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

Comment: Noted, in my case I don't actually know what the input structure will be, the helper function only focus on eliminating the edges and node from the json. I will leave it to be `any` in this case. Thanks. @vickson

Comment: Also, don't mix up "what my function expect" with "what the user is going to feed me". When making a typescript function, always state "what my function expect". You are making an implicit documentation for people to follow, and you expect them to supply you with an object of certain structure. users can always do `myFunction(myObject as any)` to forcibly call your function. It is then their responsibility to make sure `myObject` at least comply to your expected parameters

Answer (score 1):

That's what generics are for.

```
const simpleConnectionsHandler = <T>(obj: any): T => {
// Some logic to remove edges and nodes
...
}

const studentList: studentsSimplified = simpleConnectionsHandler<studentsSimplified>(responseA); 
const teacherList: teachersSimplified = simpleConnectionsHandler<teachersSimplified>(responseB);
```

Note: You could let the variable types be implied like so:

```
const studentList = simpleConnectionsHandler<studentsSimplified>(responseA); 
const teacherList = simpleConnectionsHandler<teachersSimplified>(responseB);
```

Comment: thanks @jc-ford let me have a try. But I wonder that isn't it we should prevent using "any" in a typescript project? Understand we can make use of generic here, but the "any" in obj , is it a good practice?

Comment: I'd say it depends. There are cases where you really can't know an object's type and `any` is the only choice. There is no "never use any" rule. It's a judgement call.

Comment: In some cases, for example, it doesn't really matter what the type of the object is. For instance, a logging function might take an `any` argument which it is just going to serialize and store.