# Use multiple generic parameters as object keys in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there a way to use **multiple generic parameters** as object keys in TypeScript?
[The answer I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419609/7709086) works fine when there is only one parameter, but not when there is more. The error "A mapped type may not declare properties or methods" appears if I try to declare more than one `[key in T]`.

A class I have for example:

```js
export class DynamicForm<
    K0 extends string, V0,
    K1 extends string, V1,
    ...
> {
    public get value(): {
        [key in K0]: V0;
        [key in K1]: V1; // ERROR: A mapped type may not declare properties or methods. ts(7061)
        ...
    } {
        // returning value...
    }

    public constructor(
        input0?: InputBase<K0, V0>,
        input1?: InputBase<K1, V1>,
        ...
    ) {
        // doing stuff...
    }

}
```

Basically I want to be able to return a typed value based on the generic types given in the constructor.

I could use a `[key in ClassWithAllKeys]`, but then I think I would lose the connection between `K0 <=> V0`, `K1 <=> V1`, etc.

Comment: Did you try `{ [_ in K0]: V0 } & { [_ in K1]: V1 } & ...`? In my experience it worked fine, but it may be different for your use case. Please add a minimal reproducible example preferably as a TypeScript playground too.

Comment: You could also write `{ [P in K0 | K1]: P extends K0 ? V0 : P extends K1 ? V1 : never }`. But the suggestion from @kellys is definitely the way to go as it is clearer and more conventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an intersection of mapped types:

```
public get value(): { [_ in K0]: V0 } & { [_ in K1]: V1 } {
    // returning value...
}
```