# A mapped type may not declare properties or methods - Typescript error when trying to create generic key value inteface

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to create an interface that accepts generic key and value like this

```
export interface GetModel<K extends string, T> {
    [key in K]: T;
}
```

But I'm getting this error `A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.ts(7061)`
I did find this generic interface in a [stackflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419609/16240007) but I am not sure why it is not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, this kind of mapping only work with types as [shown here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). So basically we have use it as a type like this

```
export type GetModel<K extends string, T> = {
    [key in K]: Model<T>;
};
```

And the example I was referring to was also used as a type.